# Time of the day greeting code won't work in a am/pm format

Tags: javascript

Yea so the problem is simple and I assume the solution should also be simple but I am a complete newb so no clue how it works. The code below won't work if the source of the time is in an am pm format, any idea how to make it work in both cases?

```
var today = new Date ();
var hourNow = today.getHours();
var greeting;

if (hourNow > 18) {
  greeting = 'Good Evening!';
} else if (hourNow > 12) {
  greeting = 'Good Afternoon!';
} else if (hourNow > 0) {
  greeting = 'Good morning!';
} else {
  greeting = 'Welcome!';
}

document.write('<h1>' + greeting + '</h1>');
```

Comment: Date object doesn't store data in AM/PM format. It simply stores an integer value that is the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 UTC. [See here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) . So as long as you are able to convert your time into a date object, getHours() will work fine here.

Comment: It looks that way. I wish I could just do it with (hourNow > 18 || 6PM)

Comment: Perhaps the code above is slightly different from what you are running? Date().getHours() is documented to return value between 0 and 23. If you using a different date object (not the standard javascript Date object) as the time source, and getHours() retuns in 12 hour format for that object, then you can still make this work by taking into account both getHours() and the value of AM/PM. Or better - convert your time into a 24 hour date object first, and then use it.

Answer (score 0):

As Turbo has commented, Date object doesn't store data in AM/PM format, so your code must work everywhere, and I tested in browser its working for me.

```
var today = new Date ();
console.log(today);       // Sun May 26 2019 18:04:28 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
var hourNow = today.getHours();
console.log(hourNow);     // 18
```

Comment: That's the thing it works for you because your time is in 24 hour format, mine is in 12 hour format.

So for example when it's 12:30 I still get good morning and when it is past 18 i get good afternoon.

Comment: So why then it works for you and not for me if we run the same code?

Comment: I Googled a bit but couldn't get the answer of `why yours is in 12hr format`. Can you please check anything in browser settings (not sure though), or check in other browser/system? `getHours()` always returns number 0 to 23 representing hour. Read more: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gethours.asp

Comment: Wait my system clock is in 12h format just as yours right? The code works in 24 hour format only so how can it know that 1pm is 13:00?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. The way I understand it, to the JS code the 12:59 is still 12 thus "Good morning!". So I have to set the hourNow one hour earlier. Like this:

```
   var today = new Date();
    var hourNow = today.getHours();
    var greeting;

    if (hourNow > 16) {
      greeting = 'Good Evening!';
    } else if (hourNow > 11) {
      greeting = 'Good Afternoon!';
    } else if (hourNow > 0) {
      greeting = 'Good morning!';
    } else {
      greeting = 'Welcome!';
    }

    console.log(greeting);
```

This way I will get Good Afternoon! after 12pm and Good Evening! after 5pm